# How to use paths with ingress on Pulumi?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, pulumi

Following [this pulumi walkthrough](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/crosswalk/kubernetes/app-services/), I need to expose 2 services: `kuard` and `rstudiogp` through an nginx ingress controller. The kuard app is just there to demonstrate that kubernetes is up , the rstudio app is something I'd like to add to the cluster.

I would like to access the kuard service at `apps.example.com`, and the rstudio service at `apps.example.com/rstudio`. However, I was only able to have both online at the same time by changing one of the hosts to for example `apps.example.rstudio.com`, so I have 2 hosts rather than one.

Isn't it possible to use ingress paths to expose two services using the same ingress rule? How to use the same hostname to access both services with different paths, e.g. `apps.example.com/kuard` and `apps.example.com/rstudio`?

`curl -Lv -H 'Host: apps.example.com' <PUBLIC-IP>`.

Current Kuard ingress:

```
// Create the kuard Ingress
const ingress = new k8s.extensions.v1beta1.Ingress(namekuard,
   {
        metadata: {
            labels: labels,
            namespace: namespaceName,
            annotations: {"kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "nginx"},
       },
        spec: {
            rules: [
                {
                    host: "apps.example.com",
                    http: {
                        paths: [
                           {
                                path: "/",
                               backend: {
                                    serviceName: serviceName,
                                    servicePort: "http",
                                }
                           },
                        ],
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {provider: clusterProvider}
);
```

Current RStudio ingress (see the annotated lines that I tried without success):

```
const ingress_rs = new k8s.extensions.v1beta1.Ingress(rsname,
    {
        metadata: {
            labels: labels_rs,
            namespace: namespaceName,
            annotations: {"kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "nginx"},
        },
        spec: {
            rules: [
                {
                    host: "apps.example.rstudio.com",
                    http: {
                        paths: [
                            {
                               path: "/",
                               backend: {
                                   serviceName: serviceName_rs,
                                   servicePort: "http",
                               }
                           },
//                            {
//                                path: "/rstudio",
//                                pathType: "Prefix",
//                                backend: {
//                                    serviceName: serviceName_rs,
//                                    servicePort: "http",
//                                }
//                            },
                        ],
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {provider: clusterProvider}
);
```

Comment: Based on the information from this [page about Supporting Types for Ingress](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/kubernetes/api-docs/networking/v1beta1/ingress/#supporting-types), you can try to change your `RStudio ingress` with `host: "apps.example.com"`. In  that case for serviceName `path: "/"` and `pathType: Exact`. And for serviceName_rs - `path: "/rstudio"` with `pathType: "Prefix"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the problem was with my application expecting to be served from the root url.